# Assign unique permissions without breaking the inheritance in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, unique

I have a discussion list and need to provide contribute access only to this list for all users with read access(i.e visitors). Basically, all visitors should be able to submit their comments in discussion list, but at same time no contribute access on any other lists of the child site. How can I do this without breaking the permissions inheritance from top level site??

Any workaround/ideas are appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

"without breaking the permissions inheritance from top level site" <-- not possible!

Sharepoint's permission model is based on inheritance. If you want different permissions for one particular list, different from the rest of your site - you will need to break permission inheritance (hence the name *inheritance*).

Any reason why you **don't** want to break inheritance?

Comment: this creates a problem in maintaining and tracking of the access levels especially if there are many lists/libraries across the subsites in a site collection

Comment: It indeed does increase complexity. SP2010 gives you the ability to see what user has permission on what item - for SP2007 there is codeplex. Check out the Sharepoint Access Checker Web Part: http://accesschecker.codeplex.com/ - tracking still is not that easy, you're right.